# Named parameters in JS onChange callback

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have the following:

```
    myFunction(...args) {
}
myFunction({"FirstName" : firstName, "LastName" : lastName});
```

the above works fine, I get the correct {FirstName : "Pacman"} collection

The issue  am having is with an event callback, my react Component has an

onChange event as follow:

```
onChange(name, value) {

myFunction({name:value});
}
```

this comes into my function like this: {name: "Pacman"}

how do I pass the "name" to come as the value in the name inside my onChange callback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) notation:

```
onChange(name, value) {
  myFunction({ [name]: value });
}
```

Comment: @Pacman note the brackets around "name".   By default, JS treats the left side of the colon as a string, not a variable.